# GIT rebase - multiple commits into one - still see in history

Tags: git

I am trying to make one commit from multiple commits (which are already pushed to the origin/master).

I am trying it from this tutorial:
https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/combining-multiple-commits-into-one/

```
$ git log --oneline  
c172641 Fix second file  
24f5ad2 Another file  
97c9d7d Add first file
we can combine the last two commits (c172641 and 24f5ad2) by rebasing up to the first commit:

$ git rebase -i 97c9d7d
and specify the following commands in the interactive rebase screen:

pick 24f5ad2 Another file  
squash c172641 Fix second file
which will rewrite the history into this:

$ git log --oneline  
1a9d5e4 Another file  
97c9d7d Add first file
```

This works good, until I push it to origin/master.

```
$ git pull
$ git push origin master
$ git log --oneline

RESULT IS:
******* Merge branch master...
******* THAT REBASE name...
c172641 Fix second file  
24f5ad2 Another file  
97c9d7d Add first file
```

But I want this result:

```
$ git log --oneline  
1a9d5e4 Another file  
97c9d7d Add first file
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Get help from "a dog": run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  You can leave out the "all" part after merging. Remember, *never use `git pull`*, use `git fetch` first, then A DOG, *then* merge *if* A DOG says it's OK. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you might want **force** push instead pull & push

```
$ git log --oneline  
1a9d5e4 Another file  
97c9d7d Add first file

$ git push -f origin master
```

notice: `rebase` + `force push` overwrites history, use with caution on public branch.

Comment: I try it, but I've got "Everything is up to date"

Comment: `git stash` first, then `git reset --hard 1a9d5e4; git push -f origin master`?

Comment: Thank you very much, your push force works! I didn't notice that I was in the middle of rebase... I resolve conflicts, use git rebase --continue and then push it with force to master :)